# How do I make an internal function nonpublic?

Tags: rust

I want to create a module with free sorting functions `InsertSort` and `SelectionSort`. According to Sedgwick's implementation, I want use  internal `exch` and `less` helper functions. I don't want expose them so that anyone could accidentally use them. How to achieve this goal?

Comment: Note that Rust's style is to have `snake_case` names for modules, functions, methods, and variable names. `CamelCase` names are intended for structs and enums.

Comment: Also, I feel that some of the downvotes you might receive are because this is covered in [the Rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html). It's expected to do some legwork before asking questions. If you want clarification on particular parts of the docs, feel free to include example code and specific questions about that code.

Comment: I've carefully read whole Rust guide. But maybe misunderstand some conception in comparison with C++. In C++ there are no way to hide free function in namespace, you have to define function in .cpp, without declaring in header. But, as I know there is no such conception in Rust as `header file`. That was the reason why I missed so obvious fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris says, items are private by default:

```
mod foo {
    fn helper() -> u8 { 1 }
    pub fn algorithm() -> u8 {
        helper() + helper()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo::algorithm());

    // error: function `helper` is private
    // println!("{}", foo::helper()); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write `fn` and not `pub fn`.